# Passing Table Type into HANA stored procedure as a parameter

Tags: c#, hana

I am just new to HANA database with C# and I want to know that is there any chance to pass DataTable or something into HANA stored procedure.

I know that with SQL server we can pass table type into stored procedure. Any luck with HANA?

Comment: Hana supports table type as an input parameter..but I'm not sure about the implementation details.

Comment: yes you can. Have a look at http://scn.sap.com/thread/3376895